# c++ log functions using template SFINAE for conditional compile

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, logging, sfinae

I am evaluating if it is possible to leverage C++11 features to replace logging Macros without any run-time additional cost.

I come out with this demo:

```
enum class LogLevel {
    Fatal = 0,
    DFatal = 1,
    Error = 2,
    Normal = 3,
    Verbose = 4,
    Debug = 5
};

constexpr LogLevel log_compiled = LogLevel::Normal;
LogLevel log_runtime = LogLevel::Error;

#ifdef NDEBUG
constexpr LogLevel log_fatal = LogLevel::Fatal;
#else
constexpr LogLevel log_fatal = LogLevel::DFatal;
#endif


template <LogLevel L, typename std::enable_if<(L <= log_fatal)>::type* = nullptr>
void Log(std::string message) {

    std::cout << "Fatal level: " << (int) L << " Message: " << message << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

template <LogLevel L, typename std::enable_if<(L>log_fatal && L <= log_compiled)>::type* = nullptr>
void Log(std::string message) {

    if (L <= log_runtime) {
        std::cout << "Level: " << (int) L << " Message: " << message << std::endl;
    }

}

template <LogLevel L, typename std::enable_if<(L > log_compiled)>::type* = nullptr>
void Log(std::string message) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //not compiled
    Log<LogLevel::Verbose>("Something to much usual");

    //compiled, not printed
    Log<LogLevel::Normal>("Something usual");

    //compiled, printed
    Log<LogLevel::Error>("No disk space");

    //compiled, printed, terminate in Debug mode
    Log<LogLevel::DFatal>("Unexpected contition, recoverable");

    //compiled, printed, terminate always
    Log<LogLevel::Fatal>("Unexpected contition, unrecoverable");

    return 0;
}
```

This way I handle the compile time exclusion, the runtime log level and the fatal conditions in a very consistent way.

It would probably be adapted for streams with the << operator.

My questions:

```
//not compiled
Log<LogLevel::Verbose>("Something to much usual");
```

Will this actually result in a NOOP by most compilers? Will the string exist in the code?

Is this approach a bad idea?

Comment: No, the constructor/destructor of `std::string` may have side effects and so can't be elided by the compiler. If you are worried, take a `const char *` instead and it should be optimized out.

Comment: Not answering your question, but I have always wondered about the usefulness of removing logging from a binary shipped to users. You are depriving yourself of the log messages exactly where you need them most, because you cannot run a debugger on a customer's machine, you can only have them send you the log.

Comment: In some routines (for example DSP) the logging code would delay execution for more than the remaining life of the Universe. For most cases it should be compiled, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the compiler cannot optimize away

```
Log<LogLevel::Verbose>("Something to much usual");
```

because it constructs and then destructs a `std::string`, which may have side effects (e.g., allocating and then freeing memory using possibly-replaced `::operator new` and `::operator delete`).

If you write your `Log` templates to take a `const char *` instead, however, then the call can be fully optimized out. Given

```
template <LogLevel L, typename std::enable_if<(L > log_compiled)>::type* = nullptr>
void Log(const char * ) {
}

int main() {
    Log<LogLevel::Verbose>("Something to much usual");
    return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.9 at `-O2` [compiles it](http://goo.gl/MnJeit) to simply

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
ret
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, all of those `Log<>` functions will be included in the executable code, except when the compiler can't find the appropriate template function overload. In that case you'll get a compile error. The only case when a template function is not included is when it is not used anywhere. So, non of your functions calls resolve in NOOP.