# Compiler optimization when using const bool to remove debug information

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a class with a debug function named `log(std::string s)`
I am working on a small embedded system, therefore I want to remove unnecessary strings from the binary.

I could use #define to achieve what I want, but I think it is a bad practice. Using `-Os` optimization I though I could use a `const bool` like so:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
    const bool enable_debug = false;
    void log(std::string s)
    {
        if (enable_debug) printf("%s",s.c_str());
    }

public:
    void doStuff(int i)
    {
        log("I don't want this string to appear in the binary output");
    }
};

int main()
{
    test instance;
    char input;
    std::cin>>input;
    instance.doStuff(input);
}
```

Please take a look at the output here: https://godbolt.org/z/qz7csf
. As you can see, the string is not removed from the assemby generated code, even though there is no way it can be used, because enable_debug is a const.

1. So why is it still in the output?
2. How can I create a toggle switch without using `#define`?

PS : in the end, I would like to have the bool variable external to the class, in order to switch all my classes at the same time.

Comment: The `enable_debug` value isn't checked at compile time. I think using `#if` preprocessing directive suites to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to avoid using preprocessing directives, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `std::string`. The compiler is not smart enough to see through all the `std::string` machinery, and I doubt it is even allowed to eliminate the `std::string` construction. Since the string literal is used to initialise the `std::string`, the literal cannot be eliminated either.

If you want to save a few bytes, perhaps consider [using `const char*` instead](https://godbolt.org/z/hG65fq).

Comment: Just updated the code for incorrect string usage. 
const char* works indeed but then I can't use + operators for concatenation...

Comment: @VictorCANOZ Convert to `std::string` *from within* the `if (enable_debug)` check. Or perhaps better yet, design your logger such that it doesn't require string concatenation. Why should it ever? Print one string, pring another string, done. They are concatenated in the log.

Comment: the compiler can't optimize away the construction of the string, because it can have side effects. see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353141/11641278

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I suppose that the best solution is to overload `log(std::string s)` with `log(const char* s)` This way I still can do `log("abc =" + to_string(abc))` and when the string a a simple `const char *` it will be optimized away if the bool is false. See https://godbolt.org/z/xoov1v

Comment: actually better exemple here: https://godbolt.org/z/G67oKM

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So why is it still in the output?

Because the compiler didn't do deep enough analysis to find out that it is not used.

> 2. How can I create a toggle switch without using #define?

Put debug functions, including their string literals into a separate translation unit, and don't link with that TU when you don't want them to show.

---

P.S.

The behaviour is undefined if debugging is enabled:

> ```
> printf("%s",s);
> ```

Comment: Except it _is_ performing that analysis: there is no actual call to `printf` (or, if I remove the UB with `std::cout << s;`, to `operator<<`). The issue is just the `std::string`.

Comment: @HTNW Fair enough. I changed the answer to not be so specific and wrong.